# Scraping Hotel Info by using the existing list of urls in csv file

Tags: python, selenium, tripadvisor

I have **scraped** urls of 3 hotel information pages from TripAdvisor and stored in a csv file. After importing the csv file, I have to use these 3 urls to scrape each hotel name, get the price range of each hotel and their hotel class. The tool of Selenium is used.

| Name | Link |
| --- | --- |
| The Upper House | https://en.tripadvisor.com.hk/Hotel_Review-g294217-d1513860-Reviews-The_Upper_House-Hong_Kong.html |
| Hotel ICON | https://en.tripadvisor.com.hk/Hotel_Review-g294217-d2031570-Reviews-Hotel_ICON-Hong_Kong.html |
| W Hong Kong | https://en.tripadvisor.com.hk/Hotel_Review-g294217-d1068719-Reviews-W_Hong_Kong-Hong_Kong.html |

Here is my code. When using the URL of single hotel, I can scrape the name of hotel. However, when it comes to a lot of hotels to scrape, it doesn't work. It seems there are problems in "for" loop.

```
!pip install selenium

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import csv
from time import sleep
from time import time
from random import randint

browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path= 'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\jupyterlab\chromedriver.exe')
result_list=[]

def start_request(q):
   r = browser.get(q)
   print("crlawling "+q)
   return r

def parse(text):
   container1 = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="taplc_hotel_review_atf_hotel_info_web_component_0"]')
   mydict = {}

   for results in container1:
        try:
            mydict['name'] = results.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="HEADING"]')

         except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            print('not____________________________found')
            mydict['name'] = 'null'
            result_list.append(mydict)

with open('Best3HotelsLink.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    for row in reader:
          req = row['Link']
          text = start_request(req)
          parse(text)
          sleep(randint(1,3))

import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(result_list)
df.to_csv('Detailed Hotelinfo.csv')
df
```

I also have tried to scrape the hotel class and the price range of the hotels, but in vain.
*[Hotel Class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K5xUS.png)*
[Price Range](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fU2LC.png)

I would like to seek your advice on how to fix the above problems. Many thanks.

Comment: and what is the problem? error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have lot informations to **scrape** i suggest you to reload informations each time:

try this code:

```
def parse(text):
   time.sleep(2)   # i suggzest you to add some time to wait to load the page
   container1 = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="taplc_hotel_review_atf_hotel_info_web_component_0"]')
   nbrcontainer = len(container1)
   mydict = {}

   for i in range(0, nbrcontainer):
        container1 = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="taplc_hotel_review_atf_hotel_info_web_component_0"]')
        results = container1[i]
        try:
            mydict['name'] = results.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="HEADING"]')

         except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            print('not____________________________found')
            mydict['name'] = 'null'
            result_list.append(mydict)
```

Answer (score 0):

i'm no good with selenium so here's how to catch price range and hotel class with beautifulsoup. both are inside different divs with same id (...), so it's hard to scrape. i don't think selenium can handle the first selector but the second should work though

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_data, 'lxml')
price_range=soup.select_one('div:-soup-contains("PRICE RANGE") + div').text
hotel_class=soup.select_one('#ABOUT_TAB svg[title*="bubbles"]')['title']
```

they have an API, that may be worth it if you have a lot of scraping to do on this site. the code is so bad i think it's already worth it but that's just my opinion

Comment: I agree that the code is so bad. But the lecturer hopes me to use selenium :(
But thanks for your insight as well.